# How to configure Azure Maps Indoor Module Icons?

Tags: azure, azure-maps

I've been working with the Azure maps indoor module https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/tutorial-creator-indoor-maps . In one of the tutorial videos (time stamped video of talking about icons https://youtu.be/mIDk1FSc8f4?t=2270) and in the screenshots the rooms (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-use-indoor-module the screenshot at the bottom of this page doesn't match the linked live demo) have icons associated with them, however I cannot find documentation or examples of this feature.

Currently I am using GPS coordinates of rooms to set the icons using normal azure maps functionality upon initialization as a workaround, but it would be nice if I could set an icon in the manifest.json for the indoor module for the cad drawing or use a custom set of icons like was mentioned in the example video.

Thanks for the help!

E: This [JSON link](https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/indoor/0.1/categories.json) I found seems like it may be related to the room categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style and icons used in rendering is based on the category value of units, zones, etc. The discrepancy could be driven by different category values set in the manifest.json file when uploading the drawing package. We are working to make styling experiences easier and more flexible for developers.